# Returning students list below average 60 using hashmap

Tags: java, hashmap

I have a problem to solve which gets student list whose average score is less than 60. Please help me in correcting my logic if any.

I have problem in merging the records from different courses. Here is my input and logic.

```
public ArrayList<String> getbadstudents(HashMap<String,HashMap<String,ArrayList<int>>> hm){
        double avg=0.0;

        ArrayList<String> as=new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String,ArrayList<int>> hp=new HashMap<>();
        //MERGING KEYS FROM COURSES
        for(map.entry<String,HashMap<String,ArrayList<int>>> x:hm.getentryset()){

        HashMap<String,ArrayList<int>> hk=x.getvalue();
        for(map.entry<String,ArrayList<int>> y:hk.getentryset())
           //MERGE SAME KEYS FROM DIFFERENT COURSES
            hp.putall(y.getkey(),y.getvalue());
           }
        }
    //CALCULATING AVG FROM THE MERGED KEYS
for(map.entry<String,ArrayList<int>> y:hp.getentryset())
            int sum=0;
            ArrayList<integer> al=x.getvalue();
            for(int z:al)
            sum+=z;
            avg=sum/al.size();
            if(avg<60){
          as.add(x.getkey());

}
            return as;
}
```

Input -

```
cs480   Lilly   20  30  70  
        Peter   50  40  50  
        John    70  50  70  
_____________________________

cs457   Lilly   30  70  50  
        Peter   40  60  75  
_____________________________

cs503   Lilly   40  30  20  
        Peter   70  65  35  
        John    40  55  25
```

Comment: First of all, you have the problem that your code won't even compile. `ArrayList<int>` is not allowed (it has to be an object not the primitve type). Java is casesensitive. So you have a lot of problems here (`map.entry ..` should be `Map.Entry`). You missed many braces. You even wrote some methods wrong (`getentryset()` instead of `entrySet()`). And you should work with Interfaces of the Collections (e.g. `List<..>` instead of `ArrayList<..>`) ... first change this, then maybe someone can help you

Comment: And you should consider not working with linked Collections, but making your own objects. (e.g. one class for `Student`, one for `Course`)  thats the big advanteage of oop. because its not very easy to know whats in the map inside a map inside a List .... ;)

Comment: Thats true @griFLo, actually I was writing a logic  like blue print. So I gave input and my logic. problem is with " //MERGE SAME KEYS FROM DIFFERENT COURSES " I need this logic ,  for the first for loop I need to get lilly from courses as one record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want to solve this like you said it (without a good data structure) you have to do it like that:

```
 for(map.entry<String,ArrayList<Integer>> y:hk.getentryset()){
    List<Integer> allScores;
    if(hp.get(y.getKey())==null){
        allScores = new ArrayList<>();
        hp.put(key, allScores);
    }
    else{
        allScores = hp.get(y.getKey());
    }
    allScores.addAll(y.getvalue());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go , I am giving you a code which will help you out and you should implement this code for your problem to **find average below 60**. I have taken my example in a problem so better you go for it .

```
import java.util.*;

public class QueQue {

public static float getAverage(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm, String name) {
    ArrayList<Integer> scores;
    scores = hm.get(name);
    if (scores == null) {
        System.out.println("NOT found");
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for (int x : scores) {
        sum += x;
    }
    return (float) sum / scores.size();
}

public static ArrayList<String> getBadStudents(HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm) {

    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList();

    for (Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> x : hm.entrySet()) {
        String name = x.getKey();
        double average = getAverage(hm, name);
        if (average < 8) {
            list.add(name);
        }

    }

    return list;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> hm = new HashMap<>();
    hm.put("Peter", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);
    hm.get("Peter").add(10);

    hm.put("Nancy", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Nancy").add(7);
    hm.get("Nancy").add(8);
    hm.get("Nancy").add(8);

    hm.put("Lily", new ArrayList<>());
    hm.get("Lily").add(9);
    hm.get("Lily").add(9);
    hm.get("Lily").add(8);

    ArrayList<String> foo = getBadStudents(hm);
    System.out.println(foo);

}

 }
```